# Default project setup in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I am setting up Git to use for a bunch of small projects that will be shared between a few people.  I have setup GitLab and everything is working but I would like to standardize how new projects are setup when created through the webpage.  I cant seem to find any examples or info on if this is possible but basically for every project created I want to:

1. Create a development branch
2. Set development branch as the default branch
3. Set master as a protected branch

I guess I am looking for something like a template for a bare project or config file that determines this kind of info.  Is this something I can do through GitLab?

I am using GitLab-6.9.2 installed on Centos using the RPM from their site if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not so new idea in the project. I was looking arround and found that this was [proposed here](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/3797854-create-empty-repo-on-project-creation)  (maybe elsewhere too) and they are discussing some details on the development to this date: [discussion](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/7069#issuecomment-45058682).

Here is the issue on a fork on their github repo: [Project Template for Project Creation #7069](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/7069/files#r13408601)

For the branch of this feature: [init_repo branch](https://github.com/pixel-shock/gitlabhq/tree/repo_init)

I think that is a resource for a pull request to the main project, but doesn't seem to be available yet.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question (2014), project templates were [discussed here (2015)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/3785) and [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/20797)

Custom project templates are available in [GitLab 11.2 (Feb. 2018)](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/08/22/gitlab-11-2-released/#custom-project-templates-on-the-instance-level), but only for GitLab premium.

Regular project templates, like the recent [GitLab 11.9 (March 2019)](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/03/22/gitlab-11-9-released/#project-templates-for-net-go-ios-and-pages) for .NET, Go, iOS, and Pages, are available for everybody.